# Serialization of objects requirements

Tags: java

Is it true that if I don't implement serializable then my object cannot be serialized ? What are the situations in which an object cannot be serialized in Java ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the Java serialization mechanism unless you implement `Serializable`, but it's not the only option.

You can serialize any object to XML and back using JAX-B.  You can use Google's protobuf or any other protocol if you wish.